# Getting java.lang.NullPointerException whenever I run my code

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, logic

To practice my basic programming skills over the summer I decided to write a 1dimensional motion physics problem solver. I am getting a java.lang.Nullpointerexception error whenever I try to run the program. I can't figure out what I've written incorrectly to give me the error. NOTE: Right now I am assuming the input for the solveFor variable will be "acceleration" for the sake of fixing this error:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PhysicsProblem
{
private double vI; // initial velocity  
private double vF; // final velocity    
private double t;  // time 
private double deltaX;  // change in the x value
private double accel;
private String missingVar;

public PhysicsProblem (double acceleration, double initialV, double finalV, double time, double changePosition) 
{
    acceleration = accel;
    initialV = vI;
    finalV = vF;
    time = t;
    changePosition = deltaX;    
}

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

public void getUnknownsAccel()
{
    //-----------
    // checks for another unknown value that is not accel
    //-----------
    if (missingVar.equalsIgnoreCase("time"))
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the value for time: ");
        t = scan.nextDouble();
        while (t <= 0 || !scan.hasNextDouble())
        {
            System.out.println("That is not an acceptable value!");
            t = scan.nextDouble();
        }
    }       
    if (missingVar.equalsIgnoreCase("initial velocity"))
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the value for initial velocity: ");
        vI = scan.nextDouble();
        while (!scan.hasNextDouble())
        {
            System.out.println("That is not an acceptable value!");
            vI = scan.nextDouble();
        }
    }
    if (missingVar.equalsIgnoreCase("final velocity"))
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the value for final velocity: ");
        vF = scan.nextDouble();
        while (!scan.hasNextDouble())
        {
            System.out.println("That is not an acceptable value!");
            vF = scan.nextDouble();
        }
    }
    if (missingVar.equalsIgnoreCase("delta X"))
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the value for delta X: ");
        deltaX = scan.nextDouble();
        while (!scan.hasNextDouble())
        {
            System.out.println("That is not an acceptable value!");
            deltaX = scan.nextDouble();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the class file for the program. I'm getting an error in the line 36: 
"if (missingVar.equalsIgnoreCase("time"))"

As well as getting an error in line 40 of the main program body: 
"problem1.getUnknownsAccel();"

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{

    String missingVar;      // other missing variable
    double vI = 0;
    double vF = 0;
    double t = 0;
    double deltaX = 0;
    double accel = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    PhysicsProblem problem1 = new PhysicsProblem (accel, vI, vF, t, deltaX);

    System.out.println("Which variable are you solving for? ");
    String solveFor = scan.nextLine();


    // after receiving solveFor input, assesses data accordingly

    if (solveFor.equalsIgnoreCase("acceleration"))
    {
        System.out.println("Solving for Acceleration!");
        System.out.println("Are there any other unknowns? (enter 'none' or the name " +
                "of the variable)");
        missingVar = scan.nextLine();
        do
        {
            problem1.getUnknownsAccel();
            System.out.println("Are there any other unknowns? (enter 'none' or the name " +
                    "of the variable)");
            missingVar = scan.nextLine();
        }   
        while (!missingVar.equalsIgnoreCase("none") || !missingVar.equalsIgnoreCase("acceleration"));

        if (missingVar == "none");
        {
            // Write code for finding solutions
            System.out.println("Assuming you have given correct values, the solution is: ");
        }
    }
```

Why is it throwing an exception?

Comment: `missingVar` is obviously null. Look back in the code to find out why. Where do you ever give the variable a String in the PhysicsProblem class?? Answer: you don't!!!

Comment: I wish I could replace [nullpointerexception] with [howtouseadebugger] .. see http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html (and others); as a developer, you *must* be the one who debugs your own code.

Comment: In the main body of the program:System.out.println("Solving for Acceleration!");
        System.out.println("Are there any other unknowns? (enter 'none' or the name " +
                "of the variable)");
        missingVar = scan.nextLine();

Comment: TommyD: you're wrong. Please see my answer to see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`missingVar` is obviously null. Look back in the code to find out why. And doing this, ask yourself where do you ever give the variable a String in the PhysicsProblem class?

Answer: you don't!

Note that two variables with the same name declared in different scopes are **not the same variable**. Just because your two classes have a missingVar String variable does not mean that they share the same variable, and as you're finding out, they in fact don't. The solution: set the missingVar variable in the PhysicsProblem class before trying to use it. Give the class a setter method for this.

i.e.,

```
public void setMissingVar(String missingVar) {
  this.missingVar = missingVar;
}
```

And then call the method before using the variable.

Comment: I thought it was important to explicitly point out different scopes, even if "two [different]" should imply it.

Comment: @user2246674: thank you for the improvement!

Comment: Thank you for the insight! So should I call that method within the class file or the main method? More explicitly, do I call it in the getUnknownsAccel method, or in the body where I am asking the user for the value of missingVar?

Comment: Ok so I know I'm not supposed ask multiple questions in one thread but... now after I run the program (after I fixed everything you mentioned), the program just stops running after it takes the value for one of the missing variables. This is puzzling, since I have a do/while loop in the main body so that the program does not just end.

Answer (score 1):

You never initialize `missingVar` to anything, so it's `null`.  You need to assign it something so it's not null.

Incidentally, you can switch the order in your call to avoid a `NullPointerException` here:

```
while (!"none".equalsIgnoreCase(missingVar) ||
       !"accelmissingVar".equalsIgnoreCase(missingVar));
```

Also, on this line

```
if (missingVar == "none");
```

Remove the semicolon, because that semicolon is interpreted to be the body of the `if` block, causing your actual block below to not be associated with `if` (it would then always be executed, regardless of the condition in your `if`).

Don't compare string values with `==`, which compares two objects references to see if they refer to the same object.  Use the `equals` method:

```
if ("none".equals(missingVar))
```

Comment: Bad idea to switch the order - then if the string is null it will fail silently and increase debugging time; better to explicitly check null and execute debug code if string is null